# Gage tree leaves turned brown

Tags: trees, diseases, fruit-trees, pests, plums

I have an Oullins Golden Gage tree which is 3 years old. This year, many of the leaves have turned brown with some holes in them. I live in South West England, UK and this happened in early spring - please see photos. Grateful for any advice on what this might be and whether anything can be done about it? [image]
[image]